# Jquery this selector problems

Tags: jquery, html

I want to cycle through a loop and display the status message every time the user clicks on the box, but right now it's just doing it once. I know the problem is with the `next` method, how can I display the status_message until loop execution ends?

http://jsfiddle.net/N8LMF/

### HTML

```
    <input type='textbox' class='' name='change_box'>
    <div class='alert_message'></div>
    <input type='textbox' class='' name='change_box'>
    <div class='alert_message'></div>
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=change_box]').live({
        blur: function(){
            var alert_message= $(this).next('.alert_message');
            for (var i=1; i<5; i++) {
                if(i%2 == 0) {
                    alert_message.removeClass().addClass('failure').text('failed').fadeOut(500);    
                }             
                else {
                    alert_message.removeClass().addClass('success').text('success').fadeOut(500);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Add .show() before the fadeOut and change removeClass() to removeClass('failure') or removeClass('success')

Comment: Your fiddle is using jQuery 1.8, if that is the version you are using, replace live() with on() as live() has been deprecated and marked for removal. Not only that but it is has tons of drawbacks, such as stopPropagation() not working due to the way it bubbles events always to the document and so on. All are in the documentation. I would look at `Explosion Pills` suggested solution. If you are not in 1.8, use delegate() (added in 1.4.2) instead of live() for the same reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of `removeClass()`

This removes all the classes, so you cannot select the div the next time you access it..

Try this if else loop

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
         alert_message.show()
                      .removeClass('success')
                      .addClass('failure').text('failed').fadeOut(500);
}
else {             
         alert_message.show()
                      .removeClass('failure')
                      .addClass('success').text('success').fadeOut(500);
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/N8LMF/5/)**

Comment: Actually, to be clear, it is also because of the .show() that you added. Because the fadeOut sets display:none; at the end, you must re show() the element.

Comment: @Sushanth--: fiddle and code in answer should probably be updated to include .show() as it otherwise seems not to work.

Comment: @paulKaplan thanks Paul I did not know that it worked that way.

Answer (score 4):

As the others have indicated, it won't trigger because of `.removeClass`, but there is another problem: you hide the input and never show it again.

You should also probably be using `.on` instead of `.live`:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name=change_box]', function () {
    var alert_message= $(this).next('.alert_message');
    ...
    alert_message.removeClass().addClass('failure alert_message').text('failed')
       //show so it can be faded out again
       .fadeOut(500, function () { $(this).show().text(''); });    
});
```

You must make a similar change for "success"

Answer (score 0):

When your code does `removeClass()` it removes the alert_message class too, so you cannot select it on the next pass.

Your for loop should not be there either. The way it is coded right now, you run the five times every time the event is fired. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type='textbox' class='' name='change_box' id='change_box'>
<div class='alert_message'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#change_box').keyup(function() {
        alert('Something changed.');
    });
});
```